# How to prevent Visual Studio Code from always reopening the previous files or folders?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code always seems to remember my session and reopen the files and/or projects that were open the last time I used it. It obviously behaves correctly when running it from the command line with a file or folder supplied, but when opening from a taskbar shortcut, I'd like it to default to an empty environment.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: How?? My VSCode never remembers previous sessions. It always opens with a brand new `Untitled-1` tab. It drives me nuts

Comment: @Green Currently it only remembers previous files if you have a folder/workspace opened. So just open any random folder (i chose my desktop folder) and now it remembers any file between sessions, even those not from that folder.

Comment: A big fat +1 from me because this question actually revealed to be that VS code CAN RESTORE previous session. XD Also in terms of what @Cardin states things have changed. I have the latest VS code running on Win10 and setting `"window.reopenFolders" : "all"` opens every single file no matter if it is in the currently active directory or not. Sadly it seems that VS code still doesn't support having multiple active directories because of all that "active directory = workspace".

Comment: @rbaleksandar That's still a negative. VS Code does not reopen existing non-dirty files as of ver 1.11.2, even with `"window.reopenFolders" : "all"`. To test, 1) go to `File>Close Folder`, 2) drag and drop any random file into VS Code, 3) go to `File>Exit`, 4) Relaunch VS Code, 5) Notice you get a blank VS Code editor again. In order to restore sessions, you need to have an active directory open. Any session, regardless of file location, will be remembered as long as you have an active directory. Btw, you can install `Project Manager` extension to jump between multiple active directories.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your previous statement. Yes, you need to have an active directory at all time in order for the session restore to work. I thought that you had problems with having other files opened and restored that are outside that active directory. Sorry.

Comment: Be aware, [you can lose work with this feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42701), at least in v1.19.3.

Comment: the shorted way is to go the directory of the application delete it completely and install the application again!

Comment: for those who want to open new file in the previous session (in a new tab, when VScode is off):     `"window.restoreWindows": "preserve",` https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36964

Answer (score 299, accepted):

You can also go into your settings and use the following:

<del>"window.reopenFolders": "none"</del>

which will not reopen the folders you were working on when you closed the editor.  The other options are `one` (the default) and `all`.

**Edit 2017-11-09:**

The option is now changed in latest versions.

```
"window.restoreWindows": "none"
```

See [Mathieu DOMER's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46191357/1130667).

**Edit 2018-09-12:**

Another setting related to this is the `hotExit` setting.  This has been discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36328775/1130667) answer to a related question.  To prevent reopening and remembering unsaved files, you can set this to:

```
"files.hotExit": "off"
```

But from the test I've made, when the `window.restoreWindows` setting is set to `none`, this is not needed.  I haven't tested every possible combination, so YMMV.

And to answer a question in the comments, to edit the settings, you have to open the settings file.  Some documentation can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) (at least on the date I am writing this).

**Edit 2022-03-16:**

If you prefer using a GUI to change the settings, see [D'Arcy Rittich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59740790/1130667).

Comment: I'm changing the accepted answer to this one, as I feel like the settings approach is better than a command line switch, which only affects the one shortcut.

Comment: Folders? I don't use folders. How about just files?

Comment: @Green You can have one active directory (workspace) but any number of opened files within or outside that workspace (at least as of the 26 of  April 2017 when I discovered that this setting exists at all :D).

Comment: I don't have `window.reopenFolders` as a setting option. Instead I have `window.restoreWindows`

Comment: I have an issue where VSCode opens the folder I _first ever opened_ with VSCode instead of the one I _most recently used_. I tried deleting VSCode's app data and it still defaults to the first folder I ever opened. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen  I do not, unfortunately.  I would have tried something much like you tried: backup my settings, uninstall, search for all data folders (user, system) and reinstall.

Comment: A thing that might annoy some: VS Code will still restore the workspace if it contained a tab with an unsaved file.

Comment: Worst default "feature" I have ever seen. I lost a lot of productive work time wondering what was going on and why my text file was not being updated.

Comment: where to edit the settings or what is the name of the file?

Comment: This isn't working for me when I open a folder with `code .` command. Always restores open editors and I can't stand it

Comment: Fixed my folder specific issues by doing `chmod 555 ~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/`
 Not super happy about it but it works

Comment: Switching off the Files.hotexit helped me. It was concerning when it was able to open a deleted file.

Comment: where to set this option?

Comment: I really want this to work like Chrome tab groups. I can restore them later, but it doesn't happen by default. Why not both?

Comment: Still if I open Code from cli it reopens the windows even with these settings

Comment: None of the solutions work for me. As son as I close a file that is not save it keeps opening. VSCode becomes unusable

Comment: My vscode already has this set to none, and yet the open files are restored when I open the directory.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/207933

Answer (score 124):

In VS Code:

- for Windows/Linux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (or choose **File/Preferences/Settings**) to open the settings page.
- for Mac <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (or choose **Code -> Preferences -> Settings**) to open the settings page.

then type `restoreWindows` in the **Search settings** input to filter for this setting. Set it to `none` and restart VS Code.

[image: restoreWindows]

Answer (score 47):

With latest update, it seems that the parameter has changed, now use:

```
"window.restoreWindows": "none"
```

Answer (score 20):

You can add the `-n` option to the startup of VS Code and it will always start with an empty window, not restoring your previous session.

Comment: The option is definitively there (`code --help` displays `-n, --new-window                   Force to open a new window.`) but it still reopens all previous windows. I think it's only meant to do something meaningful when the program is already running.

Comment: where is the startup? I cannot find where to add the -n. Is it a file? Can I access it via Settings?

Comment: Only this worked for me on MacOs: "code -n ~/myFolder/myCodeFolder"

Answer (score 3):

**Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings**

In the **"Search Settings"** bar type **Restore Windows**. You will see **Window:Restore Windows**. Set it to **none**.

**Or...**

On the side menu, **User** should be underlined and you should see options like:

- Text Editor
- Workbench
- Window
- Features
- Applications
- Security
- Extensions

Click on **Window** and scroll down on the main page until you see **Restore Windows**.
Put the setting to **none**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

***01 December 2018***

This works for me. i.e. `"C:\Users\Sampath\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" -n`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of above is working while I'm trying to close "dirty" unsaved files which I accidentally edited 1000 files and wanted to ignore saving all of them.

My fix was adding this line into settings.json:

```
    "files.hotExit": "off"
```

Open up vscode, close vscode and just click the confirmation button to close all of the files without saving.

Then open back vscode and boom.. no more unsaved files being shown.

Comment: Where did you find `settings.json`?

Comment: @CB_Ron you can find your settings.json file here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations

Answer (score 0):

If `"window.restoreWindows": "none"` not solve the problem,
then try to run code as root -> `sudo code --user-data-dir` code files and restart code normally without root.

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me

Right-click on Shortcut and add --disable-gpu to Target as per screen shot.

[image]

Comment: This works for me in both regular vs code and vs code insiders

Answer (score 0):

To stop it remembering open tabs (MacOS):

```bash
$ rm ~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/*
# chown root ~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage
```

Comment: Doesn't delete other things _aside_ from just the previously opened tabs/files?

Comment: @GinoMempin I have not noticed any issues and I have used this for some time