# How to reopen last opened file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

If i close the vscode editor after saving a file and reopen the editor again, the session is not restored.  I am unable to find the file in open recent. The only way how can I open the file is navigating to the directory in `open` menu. Thats very annoying is it some problem with my editor or default behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code never reopens previous file or folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328104/visual-studio-code-never-reopens-previous-file-or-folder)

Answer (score 2):

You must have a folder opened to restore previously opened files.

- Go to 'File' menu
- Open folder
- Select a folder (my documents for example)

Now open any files, close vscode and re-open. Your files are still in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

`"window.restoreWindows": "all"` will do ;)

Answer (score 0):

The complete settings are

```yaml
"window.restoreWindows": "all",
"files.hotExit":"onExitAndWindowClose",
```

Note that with:

- [VSCode 1.42 (Jan. 2020)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_42#_documentationrefactoring-contribution-point) it does work even in case of "[hot exit](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/30/hot-exit-in-insiders)" (unexpected exits): see "[Visual Studio Code never reopens previous file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59591384/6309)".
- VSCode 1.51 (Oct. 2020), that will **also restore a search tab** if you had one ([issue 102659](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102659) resolved by [issue 99694](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99694), and [commit 8bf0e20](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/8bf0e20f9605274843677029a94c5ac17fb12718))