# How to pick from a list of previously opened files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

One of the most useful features of Sublime Text for me was that it keep a history of all the files that I opened. How can I get this functionality in VS Code?

The list of previously opened files/editors when I open `cmd+p` is really small and it doesn't persist across sessions.

**Edit**: the problem isn't that I lose my previously opened files when I close the session, but that there is no convenient way of accessing a file I opened a week ago, for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code never reopens previous file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328104/visual-studio-code-never-reopens-previous-file-or-folder)

Comment: @MatheusCuba It's not really the same issue. I have no problem re-opening files after closing VS Code. It's just that I can't re-open files from previous sessions

Comment: Is CMD+R any better?  It should bring up a long list of recently opened folder and files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how I missed this: `File | Open Recent | More` it's assigned to action `workbench.action.openrecent`.

The only thing I'd like to know is if there is a way of setting the number of files it remembers (the buffer size).

Comment: This only opens project folders, not files I've edited

Answer (score 15):

To see a list of recently opened files (as of v1.42) try this in the command palette:

`View: Show All Editors By Most Recently Used`

or use this command `workbench.action.showAllEditorsByMostRecentlyUsed` in a keybinding.

Comment: This seems to be a much smaller list than what I see with `control-p`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It only shows **currently opened files**. Doesn't show files that were opened but then closed, doesn't show files opened in other VSCode Windows and obviously doesn't show previously opened files if the computer has been restarted. Accepted answer (with only 2 upvotes) is much better answering the question.

Answer (score 14):

On mac it's ⌘ + P.

I'm using mac monterey

Answer (score 1):

You simply click Ctrl-P to see the list of recently opened files (regardless of whether they are still open or not).

You can even search by file name at this point if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show recent projects, you can use:

```
Control + R
```

on Mac. Hope, it helps!

Answer (score -1):

should be `cmd + tab` to open recently opened files

Comment: ⌘ + Tab switches between windows on macOS. This is not a shortcut of VS Code.