# Visual Studio Code doesn't remember opened files / won't remember "open with" files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can't seem to find the solution for this. My current VSCode version is the latest, 1.29.1.

OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit 
Bios: Phoenix BIOS SC-T v2.1 
Processor: IntelCore i5-5300u 
Memory: 8192MB RAM

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36328775/6309), Visual Studio Code will remember opened files if the following settings are set:

```
files.hotExit: "onExit"
window.restoreWindows": "all",
```

Regarding the "open with" feature, see [vscode issue 12147](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12147) for illustration:

You need to activate that option during the install process:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/24956907/25698735/5c140fce-30c0-11e7-95a7-45e9f4834fb5.png]