# Visual Studio Code how to prevent load all previously open tabs when I open the project again

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

Think I'm working on a project with open 10 tabs.
When I close the project and open it in next time, VS code remembered those all 10 tabs and open those with the project opening.
It's really annoy thing.
How do I prevent this behavior.

Close all the tabs before you close the project will be a solution. But I'm looking for a solution more than that.

Comment: My mistake. =) Thanks!

Comment: "window.restoreWindows": "none",

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code always reopens previous file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270774/visual-studio-code-always-reopens-previous-file-or-folder)

Comment: This is something different window.restoreWindows": "none always start with an empty workspace. I'm already using this. When I open a folder I want it open without any tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If you type code on the command line, VScode will open with all tabs from previous time opened too. If you type 'code myfile', VScode will open with only a tab for myfile, where myfile is an existing file.