# Make Visual Studio Code open in clean state

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work in multiple projects spread in multiple folders on macOS.
I usually start working on them by running:

```
cd ~/workspace/project-a
code .
```

That **always** causes a new window to be open with the last files I worked on that project. My next move is to close all tabs, if the editor was split I have to do that as many times as split editors I had.

Is there a setting that would allow me to always start on a clean state?

My settings that I believe are related to this issue are the following:

```
"window.restoreWindows": "none",
"files.hotExit": "onExitAndWindowClose",
```

I tried `off` for `files.hotExit` but the behaviour remained the same.

Also if possible, where is this information stored (open files for given folders)? Is that a dot file inside the folder or elsewhere inside Visual Studio Code installation?

Comment: which platform do you use ? Linux or OS X ?

Comment: Which version of VSCode you using? Have you tried using `code -n .`. Also `"window.restoreWindows": "none",` works great for me. I have checked on Mac OSX and Code 1.24.1

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are on the latest VSCode (1.24.1 as on 18-Jun-18)

Then make sure you have below in your settings

```
"window.restoreWindows": "none",
```

Make sure there are no `JSON` errors in your custom settings file. This also could cause the settings to be not loaded at all.

Next try launching the folder using

```
code -n .
```

Also `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups/workspaces.json` contains the information of open workspaces

Also refer to below thread

[Visual Studio Code always reopens previous file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270774/visual-studio-code-always-reopens-previous-file-or-folder)

Comment: So pretty much the same conclusions: `-n`, `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/Workspaces`?

Comment: Yeah, I had first wanted post it as comment and confirm (5 min before your answer :-)). And later as an answer

Comment: I am on 1.24.1, settings are like you described I thought `-n` would do the trick but it did not :( It opened the folder with 5 files that were previously open. I could not open `workspace.json` maybe there is something with my installation and I should do a clean one?

Comment: You have installed it using brew or direct download?

Comment: @DaniloCabello, can please provide information on the last comment?

Comment: @TarunLalwani direct download and auto-update after that.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I see the CLI has an option to point to a different `user-data-dir` and I also tried `--verbose --log debug` but I can't find where my user data directory is to investigate where the files are being remembered.

Comment: Can you remove the app and install it using brew?

Comment: I got a brand new computer, the issue persists if I open a folder, any folder and open a few files, later when I open that folder again all files will be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You could try, in addition of the setting  `"window.restoreWindows": "none"` to start with:

```
code -n
```

That would force a new VSCode Window to be opened.

> Also if possible, where is this information stored (open files for given folders)?

See [issue 3884](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3884)

```
# Windows
%APPDATA%\Code\Workspaces
# Mac
$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code
$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/Workspaces
$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups/workspace.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Window > Open Folders In New Window
set it to off

[image: Open Folders In New Window]