# Visual Studio Code how to change setting to NOT restore old session, open every time new window, new session

Tags: visual-studio

can anyone help me out, how to set up Visual Studio Code to open every time, new session.

thanks Nancy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36797180 hope this helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code always reopens previous file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270774/visual-studio-code-always-reopens-previous-file-or-folder)

Answer (score 1):

You can launch VS Code from the command line to quickly open a file, folder, or project. Typically, you open VS Code within the context of a folder. To do this, from an open terminal or command prompt, navigate to your project folder and type `code . -n` or `code . --new-window`

Comment: Alternatively, the answer by @Asmaa3107 works as well. Go to your settings, search for `Restore Windows` and change the option to `none`,

Answer (score 0):

try go to setting page and select this choice 
[image]