# How do you stop VS Code from loading a corrupt file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidently opened a file that didn't have a suffix, just "file.", that doesn't even exist and now whenever I try to close it, VS Code crashes. When I reopen Code, it always reopens the file. I've scoured settings and tried these fixes but nothing helps.

[Visual Studio Code always reopens previous file or folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270774/visual-studio-code-always-reopens-previous-file-or-folder)

How can I completely clear the cache for VS code and stop reopening files? It should be possible outside of VS Code because I get the feeling settings aren't be preserved because of the corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I was able to track down the call to the file in $HOME/.config/Code/Backups. Once I removed the offending Backup file, I can open Code once again without loading the corrupt file.