# I don't want to "reopen" any file (previous unclose file) when I open the workspace (directly) in the visual studio code. How could I set it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want to "reopen" any file (previous unclose file) when I open the workspace (directly) in the visual studio code. How could I set it?

I have already tried the following answer, but not work for me:
[How to prevent Visual Studio Code from always reopening the previous files or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270774/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-code-from-always-reopening-the-previous-files-or-fo/59740790#59740790)