# How to prevent vs code to open multiple previous tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open my vscode for new project it's showing me multiple tabs of my previous work how can I solve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Visual Studio Code from always reopening the previous files or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270774/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-code-from-always-reopening-the-previous-files-or-fo)

Answer (score 0):

I think your default settings in VS Code is set to "OPEN IN A NEW WINDOW". If that is the issue you should change the settings