# Visual Studio Code keeps files open after exit

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open a single file in Visual Studio Code, then exit Visual Studio Code, the file is re-opened next time I open Visual Studio Code.
I'd like to start fresh every time. Surprisingly I can find no information on how to change this behavior.
How can I force Visual Studio Code to close all tabs when I exit the application?
Environment: Windows 10.

I tried searching for a solution on Google / stack overflow. Lots of unrelated information but nothing about this.

Comment: I believe it is called a Workspace.

Comment: What about "Window: Restore Windows"? "Controls how windows are being reopened after starting for the first time." With `none`, previous windows will never be reopened; only a single blank window will be created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Visual Studio Code from always reopening the previous files or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270774/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-code-from-always-reopening-the-previous-files-or-fo)