# How to make VSCode open in a previous session after opening a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Current behaviour: When I open a file and vsc is not running (no window opened) it overrides the old session.
Desired behaviour: When opening a new file vsc would restore the old session and open the new file in it.
When a window is already open it works like that.
If it's possible please let me know.

Comment: related to /answered by?: [How to prevent Visual Studio Code from always reopening the previous files or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270774/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-code-from-always-reopening-the-previous-files-or-fo)

Comment: @Luuk which answer there? have you verified yourself?